# Use accents in maths mode - conflit with amsmaths

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, accents

I would like to insert the following command

```
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
```

but when I load the package accents

```
\usepackage{accents}
```

I have the following conflict with the amsmath package about the (re)definition of
the \dddot command.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \dddot already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

Comment: Page 3 in the manual of `accents`: “If you use accents with `amsmath`, you must load `accents` after [it]”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is solved by loading the amsmath package before !

Comment: The order of package loading can cause and solve a number of issues.  Welcome to the site.